# Android: Linear acceleration without deceleration

Tags: android

I am developing a car racing game. The car moves on its own in the forward direction. Only **2 controls** are provided to user:

- When the player moves his device to the right, I mean linear movement of device, the car will turn right.
- Same goes for turn left.

I'm using `Sensor.TYPE_LINEAR_ACCELERATION` for this purpose. The **problem** is:

- When I move the device to the right, the car moves to the right and then comes back to its original position.

**I think** it is because when I start moving the device, there is some positive acceleration, so the car turns right. But when the device stops, there is some negative acceleration (deceleration) too, which causes the car to turn left.

How can I achieve what I want?

Comment: use the gyroscope to detect the orientation instead of the acceleration.

Comment: I don't want rotational motion. I want linear motion. Side to side movement of device while keeping it flat.

Comment: can't do that. you can't distinguish between constant speed and no speed (because that is a constant speed after all) (all games in the word use rotation, though, why not yours?)

Answer (score 1):

I have not worked with `Sensors` on Android, but the acceleration should be negative as the device comes to a stop. Your code should account for this based on the interval of time between each `SensorEvent`:

```
private long previousTimestamp = 0;

private double velocity = 0;

public double getDistance(float acceleration, long timestamp) {
    double time = (timestamp - previousTimestamp) / 1E9;
    previousTimestamp = timestamp;

    double distance = (velocity * time) + (0.5 * (acceleration * (time * time)));
    velocity += acceleration * time;

    return distance;
}
```

Comment: Can you explain a little on how can I then use this distance to map onto my car controls?

Comment: I'm getting completely random values of distance every every time.

Comment: @SalmanYounas It should be the change in distance. So, if you are working along the x-axis, you should be able to just add these values to the car's position along that axis (`position += distance`). Though, these should be the real-world distances, so you may want to scale them down for use in your game (i.e. `position += (distance * scalefactor)`).

Comment: Your function is returning distance or change in distance? If that's the distance, I'll find delta distance and then map it.

Comment: @SalmanYounas It is the change in distance, sorry for the misleading method name.

Comment: Every time I start my game, I see different values of this change in distance, ranging from let's say -1239 to 1380 and sometimes 0.00582 etc. I'm not able to map the change in distance onto my car. Any ideas?

Comment: @SalmanYounas How are you changing the distance on your car? If you can't use the change in distance, you should at least be able to use the absolute distance with a global variable; `private double distance = 0`, then on each update set `distance += getDistance(acceleration, timestamp)`. You may have to play with the scaling a bit to get it to work right with your game. You also might want to cast the distance to an integer (`(int) Math.round(distance)`), depending on how your game is rendered.